# Select query to retrieve text column with hyphen, comma, period and parantheses

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Thanks for taking time to read my question.

I have created a MySQL table, a HTML form and a program in PHP which connects the form to MySQL table and retrieves sequences for column `Annotations` which is `text` data type.

This column has characters and also has one or more of hyphen, comma, parentheses, period or spaces.

Please look at the following code that I used for select query:

```
$values=mysql_query("SELECT Sequence 
                       FROM oats 
                      WHERE Foldchange = '$Foldchange' AND 
                            RustvsMockPvalue = '$RustvsMockpvalue' AND 
                            Annotations REGEXP '%$Annotation%[-]+'");
```

Here `$Annotation` is the form variable which holds the value entered by the user in the form. `Annotations` is the column name in the MySQL table.

`Annotations` column has characters `A-Z` or `a-z` and one or more of hyphen, comma, space or parentheses like the following.

`Sequence` is another `text` column in the MySQL table but does not have `,./()`.

Example data from `Annotations` column:

> ADP, ATP carrier protein,  mitochondrial precursor (ADP/ATP translocase) (Adenine nucleotide translocator) (ANT).

I am not able to retrieve Sequence column data when I search for any `Annotations` column data with comma, parentheses, period and slash. It works fine for those records which does not have these `,.()/`.

I tried to use `LIKE` instead of `REGEX` but it didn't work either.

A record from mysql table:(columns that you see below: contigid,source,genelength,rustmeans, mockmeans,foldchange,pvalue,rustmockteststatistic,Annotations and Sequence)

as_rcr_contig_10002 ORME1   2101    506.33  191 -2.18   2.21E-10    -6.35   Tesmin/TSO1-like,  CXC domain containing protein.   AACAATTCCCCTCAACCAACCTTTTATTTCATCCCATTTTTATCATCTGTCCGGTTACAGATTTTGCTTCCAGTTAGGTGCCACTTCTTCAAACGCTCAACCCTTACCCACTACCACCCCACCAAAACCAACCCCCCAAGATGCAGTTCATCACTCTCGCCGTTGCTTTTGCTTTCTTTGCTGGTGCCANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTTTTGCTTTCTTTGCTGGTGCCACCTCGTCGCCGGTTTCCATGGACCCCAAAGCCGAGAAGTCCGGCTCCTCGGGATCCGGTGGCGCCCCTCTGGGCACTGCTAGCCCCTATCCCCAAAGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGGTGGCCCTCAGTCGCCAGGCTCTGGCCAACCCGGTAGGATGCCATGGGGTAGCGACCAATCTGCCTACGGTGGTGGTTTCCCTTATGGATCATTCCCCTCGGTTTCGGGGCAATCCCAATCGACGGCCTATGCTCAAGCTCAATCATCCAGTTTCCCCTCAAACGGTGTCCCGACACACTCCTCGGCCTCCGCCCAAGCGCAATCATCCGGTCCTGGACAAGCTCAGGCAGCCGCTTCTGCCCAGGTTCCCGGCGGCCCCCACGGTCAAGGTTCTAACGGATTTGGCGCACAAGGCCAGTTTGGACAGAACGGGCAGAACGGCCTCTATGGTCAAGACGGCAATGGCTTTAGTGCCCAAGGCCAATTTGGACAGAGTGGACAGAATGGCTTCTATGGTCA

Could someone please help me in the correct syntax of the `SELECT` syntax? Thank you.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to understand, could you give 3/4 lines of your table, an input and which lines you want it to select?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the post with an input from the table.

Comment: use PDO [forget the mysql extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to familiarise yourself with regex - it's its ownittke language.

Use REGEXP with the right regex:

```
WHERE ...
AND Annotations REGEXP '[-A-Za-z(). ]+'
AND Annotations NOT_REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+'
```

If mysql supported regex look aheads, this could be done in one test.
,

Comment: Thanks for your response Bohemian.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not using REGEXP properly.
You should check the differences between LIKE and REGEXP.

REGEXP use Regular expresions, which have very particular syntax.
LIKE use simple text remplacement with key characters like `%` or `_`

Here you are using REGEXP with %, that's why it's not working. `%` is a key character for LIKE only.
But in REGEXP, `.` and `-` are special characters that you need to escape to.

If you want to check several characters, REGEXP is the way to go :

`Annotations REGEXP '.*$Annotation.*[\-(),\.]+.*'`

This match :

- .* : 0 to n characters
- $Annotation : Your keyword
- .* : 0 to n characters
- [\-(),\.]+ : At least 1 character from the list : - ( ) , .
- .* : 0 to n characters

Tell us if that match your data.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I get the difference between REGEXP and like. It matches to few data not all. for example if you see the following it has ( or ) or ,  or . or / or \ occuring many times at different places.

Comment: Could you Edit your post one more time to give us examples that didn't match and you would like to match ?

Comment: Thank you Thibault for the nice explanation and a quick response. I get the difference between REGEXP and like. It matches to few data not all. for example if you see the following it has ( or ) or ,  or . or / or \ occurring many times at different places.                                                             Similar to Arginyl-tRNA--protein transferase 1 (EC 2.3.2.8) (R-transferase 1) (Arginyltransferase 1) (Arginine-tRNA--protein transferase 1). Splice isoform ATE1-2.
I am not sure how this could be done.

Comment: Thibault,Here are few more examples:                           SFT2-like family protein.(didn't work for the above REGEXP)
Tesmin/TSO1-like,  CXC domain containing protein.

Comment: How about this :

<code>
Annotations LIKE '%$Annotation%' AND Annotations REGEXP '.*[\-(),\.]+.*' 
</code> 
?

Comment: Thibault, Let me try the new one. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code that you had suggested above and it didn't work for this Annotation                                                     SFT2-like family protein.

Comment: Maybe you souldn't escape the \- then. Try  REGEXP '.*[-(),.]+.*'

Comment: where Annotations REGEXP '[-]+'; should match "Annotation SFT2-like family protein."
If not, are you sure it is a regular dash ? Or maybe it's a mdash ?

Comment: Thibault, Annotations column data is the output from another application. But please tell me how you differentiate between regular dash, mdash and a hyphen when you open this column data in Excel?Thanks again.

Comment: The way that - is used is all for compounded words. so it should be a hyphen if I check the entries for that column.

Comment: Can you give us access to a file with an extract of your data? So we are sure that data is not altered.

Comment: Is there a way to send few lines of data which is a csv file that you wanted to have a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't craft a Regular Expression that would work in your case without getting into some crazy matching schemes (orders and so forth), In order to find what you're looking for, you'll need to custom construct the SQL statement and luckily you're using PHP.

Here I'm starting with a simple space delimited entry. Remember that you can't wrap something with parenthesis because the parenthesis might not match up in your result set.

```
$search_input = 'ADP ANT'; 

//example of array from a search page full of check boxes or fields
$annSearches = explode(' ',$search_input);

/*annSearches is now and array with ADP,ANT*/


$sql = "SELECT Sequence FROM oats WHERE Foldchange = '$Foldchange' AND RustvsMockPvalue = '$RustvsMockpvalue'";

foreach ($annSearches as $Annotation){
    $sql .= " AND Annotations LIKE '%$Annotation%'";
}
```

The output SQL statement would look like this (wrapped for clarity):

```
SELECT Sequence FROM oats WHERE
Foldchange = '$Foldchange'
AND RustvsMockPvalue = '$RustvsMockpvalue'
AND Annotations LIKE '%ADP%'
AND Annotations LIKE '%ANT%';
```

If you do a really long query, this will get slower and slower as MySQL has to run through every record in the database over and over for the results.

**FULLTEXT SEARCH OPTION**

Another way that you could potentially do this is to enable [FULLTEXT search](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/) functionality on the Annotations field in the table in the database.

```
ALTER TABLE oats ADD FULLTEXT(Annotations);
```

This would allow you to do a search something like this:

```
Sequence FROM oats WHERE
Foldchange = '$Foldchange'
AND RustvsMockPvalue = '$RustvsMockpvalue'
MATCH(Annotations) AGAINST ('ADP ANT')
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and example. In the place of $search_input will I be able to use $Annotation which holds the value from the form(Textbox) where the user enters the search text for Annotation for example: Tesmin (I shown the record above in the other post).